# How is Mustache used in Jhipster Lite?

Tags: jhipster

Great work on [Jhipster Lite](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-lite)!

The goal is to integrate Mustache templates into a project called [sql-to-jdl](https://github.com/Blackdread/sql-to-jdl) I have been contributing to lately. Currently my preliminary work uses [mustache.java](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java/).

Does [Jhipster Lite](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-lite) use a Java or JavaScript implementation of mustache and how is the dependency added to the project?

I have been looking into how Mustache is being used in [Jhipster Lite](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-lite), but I cannot find any maven or npm dependency for [mustache.java](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java/) or [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/).

I tried

```
mvn compile dependency:tree
```

and

```
npm ll
```

However, I could find no reference to anything related to mustache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been removed in favor of [ArgumentsReplacer.java](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-lite/blob/main/src/main/java/tech/jhipster/lite/module/domain/file/ArgumentsReplacer.java)

https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-lite/discussions/4682#discussioncomment-4370202